# I get a black screen after loging on ubuntu vm after update

Tags: boot, display, display-resolution, login-screen

I had similar problem before but it was caused by bad controller.
Things i tried:

- reinstalling VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
- changing Graphics Controller
- changing CPU, video Memory
- tried recovery mode but it didn't help

I had similar problems before but last time I was struggling to have correct resolution (I have 2560x1440) but after some time I managed to do it. The only time I remember having it was while I was trying to change resolution to larger and ubuntu didn't let me. I had a black screen there but it usually restarted after reboot.

Here are pictures and I can provide any information necessary.

[image: Display settings]

[image: Storage]

[image: ubuntu logo is showing]

than there is only black screen
But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> works

[image: Login page]

After I login I can see cursor in black (After boot I don't)
The only thing I can think of is that ubuntu doesn't like my resolution again but I changed it permanently in a file to 2560x1440.

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Thanks for edit :)

Answer (score 0):

So I was using this method to apply my custom resolution https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/
the last step with saving the file seems to cause the display to bug and display only black box. If you encounter the same problem you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3-6</kbd> login for vm is machine and password is your password.

Than write sudo nano ~/.profile
Edit out added lines and save <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
Than reboot (by a reboot command) and it should work.